# MVC - How to render a 'a href' link in a View that's been stored in a database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

**Question background:**

I have an MVC4 app whos homepage data is supplied from a `View Model`.

**The Issue:**

Within the `View Model` I have a property called `AboutUsDescOne` This is set from the `Controller` and `Action Method` from data that has been retrieved from a database. Within the data set on the property is a `a href` link, The following shows the text stored in the database:

```
This is the website Google <a href="https://google.com/">Google</a> click the link.
```

The issue I'm having is when I render the data in the `View` the `a href` is being seen as text in the `View` and is ***not*** showing as a link, as shown:

[image]

**The Code:**

The propety is simply set as a propety on a standard ViewModel:

```
public string AboutUsDescOne {set; get;}
```

This is how it is then rendered in the View:

```
<div class="col-md-8 form-group">
   <p>
      <h4>@Model.HomePageVM.AboutUsDescOne</h4>
   </p>
</div>
```

**Can anyone tell me how to get the link to render in the View?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<h4>@Html.Raw(Model.HomePageVM.AboutUsDescOne)</h4>
```

Use this helper with caution though. If a user can edit this block of HTML then you might be making yourself vulnerable to an XSS attack:

> Text output will generally be HTML encoded. Using Html.Raw allows you to output text containing html elements to the client, and have them still be rendered as such. Should be used with caution, as it exposes you to cross site scripting vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So in my case am I ok to use `Html.raw`? I've read else where that it is bad practice to use it with user inputted data. As my data is rendered from the model I should be ok?

Comment: If the data you are putting into the model comes from a user editable field then you might want to look into sanitizing the HTML first. If its just coming from a DB or something then youll be fine.